How to export all pages in Google Sheets tab page to PDF?
This is the function we use to export the content of a Google Sheets file to a PDF file in Drive:
function createPDF(ssId, sheet, pdfName, folder) {
  /**
   * Creates a PDF for the customer invoice template sheet
   * @param {string} ssId - Id of the Google Spreadsheet
   * @param {object} sheet - Sheet to be converted as PDF
   * @param {string} pdfName - File name of the PDF being created
   * @return {file object} PDF file as a blob
   */
  const fr = 0, fc = 0, lc = 9, lr = 27;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + ssId + "/export" +
    "?format=pdf&" +
    "size=A4&" +
    'fitw=true&' +                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
    "fzr=true&" +
    "portrait=true&" +
    "fitw=true&" +
    "gridlines=false&" +
    "printtitle=false&" +
    "top_margin=0.5&" +
    "bottom_margin=0.25&" +
    "left_margin=0.5&" +
    "right_margin=0.5&" +
    "sheetnames=false&" +
    "pagenum=UNDEFINED&" +
    "attachment=true&" +
    "gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +
    "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r2=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc;

  const params = { method: "GET", headers: { "authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
  const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob().setName(pdfName)

  const pdfFile = folder.createFile(blob)
  return pdfFile
}

This code works fine but only exports the first page. There are 2 pages in a single Google Sheet tab. How is it possible to export the complete sheet in the tab? Just like the GUI does?

So you've made no effort to solve this for yourself. You just want someone to modify it for you - that's not how Stackoverflow it meant to work. Its not a free scripting service. At least make the attempt. Here's a hint, you can fetch the sheetids for each tab in a loop and then generate pdfs one-by-one by making a small change to the script above. Take a stab at it, come back with your results and then we can provide you with feedback.

That is not correct, I just didn't post my failed tests. Found it in the meantime here. Needed to use "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r3=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc; to include the seconde page.

As Louis remi said here, gid (grid id) is the sheet filter. Remove
"gid=" + sheet.getSheetId() + '&' +


We're making progress.. when removing that line it exports all sheets in the workbook, not just the one sheet and everything on it.

Found it here. Needed to use "r1=" + fr + "&c1=" + fc + "&r3=" + lr + "&c2=" + lc; to include the seconde page.

@DarkLite1 I don't understand your comment: not just the one sheet and everything on it.. My link in the question has details aboutother parameters like r1 for first row...
